# Default var if "$(this).attr('data-id')" is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm learning "on the fly" so please pardon my ignorance.  I'm trying to figure out how to pass a default "folderID" to my #next and #prev click functions below.  Am I on the right path?  Or totally off base?  Thanks so much for your time. K

```
$(function() {

var folderID = $('.folderID').attr("data-id"); 



$("#next").click(function() {
var myInbox = "/test/SecComm/ajax_inboxResults.cfm?startRow="+nextstart;
myInbox+="&folderID="+folderID;
    $.get(myInbox,function(data){
      $("#messageList").html(data);
  });
})

$("#prev").click(function() {
var myInbox = "/test/SecComm/ajax_inboxResults.cfm?startRow="+prevstart;
myInbox+="&folderID="+folderID;
    $.get(myInbox,function(data){
      $("#messageList").html(data);
  });
})

$(".folderID").click(function() {
var folderID = $(this).attr('data-id');                               
<cfoutput>var myInbox = "/test/SecComm/ajax_inboxResults.cfm
folderID="+folderID;</cfoutput>
    $.get(myInbox,function(data){
      $("#messageList").html(data);
  });
})
```

})

```
var prevstart = 1
var nextstart = 1


function showPrev(newprevstart){
prevstart = newprevstart
$("#prev").show()
}

function hidePrev(){
$("#prev").hide()
}

function showNext(newnextstart){
nextstart = newnextstart
$("#next").show()
}

function hideNext(){
$("#next").hide()
}
```

Comment: I advise you to use the live: $(".folderID").live("click", function() {

Answer (score 17):

You could try the following:

```
var folderID = $(this).attr('data-id') || 1;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XAPdw/)

The above assigns the value of the `data-attribute` to the variable `folderID`, if the selector doesn't return a match then it assigns the default value of `1`.

In 2016, and quite probably since 2015, it's possible instead to use several means of acquiring the `data-id` attribute-value using the DOM – as well as jQuery – those options are below:

```
var folderID = $(this).data('id'); // jQuery
var folderID = this.dataset.id;
var folderID = this.getAttribute('data-id');
```

Obviously all of these require the `this` to be the appropriate element from which you wish to retrieve the attribute-value.

A comment raised below points out the obvious flaw in the above:

> Please note that if you have a `data-id` of 0, this will use the value 1 instead (0 being a falsy value).

With that in mind it's worth revisiting the problem, to show a very similar solution but using a check that the `data-id` is present:

```
var folderID = 'undefined' !== typeof this.dataset.id ? this.dataset.id : 1;
```

With the above we check whether the type of (`typeof`) of the referenced property is not equal (`!==`) to `undefined`; if it is not equal to `undefined` we retrieve the value stored in that property (the property-value of `this.dataset.id` being the attribute-value of the `data-id` attribute) or, if it is `undefined` then we supply the value of `1`.

This approach uses the Conditional (ternary) Operator, in which an expression is evaluated for `true`/`false` (or `truthy`/`falsey`) and, if the expression evaluates to `true`/`truthy` then the first statement following the `?` character is used. If the expression evaluates to `false`/`falsey` then the second statement, following the `:`, is used:

```
var variableName = expression ? ifTrue : ifFalse;
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/conditional_operator).
  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: Please note that if you have a `data-id` of 0, this will use the value `1` instead (0 being a falsy value)

Comment: Ryan, good catch(and +1); I hadn't thought of that. Is there a workaround to that problem, or is a comparison of some sort necessary?

Comment: Well, if you know there will never be an ID of 0, it doesn't matter. For instance, database IDs generally start at 1, so it's a non-issue. Otherwise, you'll probably have to go with a ternary or a full-blow `if... else`.

Answer (score 1):

Normal shorthand would be:

```
var folderID = $(this).attr('data-id') || 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path, although I would store the result of your selector `$(this).attr('data-id')` in a variable so you don't have to perform a look up on the DOM again.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already got a 'data-id' attribute on your element, you could just find the value of that attribute from within the functions.

```
$("#next").click(function() {

// Get the value of the custom data value
var folderID = $('.folderID').attr("data-id");

var myInbox = "/test/SecComm/inboxResults.cfm?startRow="+nextstart;
myInbox+="&folderID="+folderID;
    $.get(myInbox,function(data){
      $("#messageList").html(data);
  });
})
```

Comment: WOW, thank you all so much for your fast responses.   I must be missing something somewhere, because the default folderID value of 1 is always passed.  (I'll update the code I've tried above.)

Comment: Does your element have the correct `class="folderID"` on it, so that it can find the element and the `data-id=""`

Comment: Hello, yes it definatley does.  If I click through the folderIDs I get the expected message results.  It's when I use the "Next" functions, the current folderID is not being passed.